# Shopware 5.6 override class method

Tags: php, symfony, shopware

I want to override method `ajaxAddArticleCartAction` in `engine/Shopware/Controllers/Frontend/Checkout.php`, cuz i want a bit complicated logic on accessories quantity calculation.

My question is: Is it possible to override this method in my custom plugin. With other words, if i add product in cart, i want to use my function (in plugin), not the Shopware one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What keeps you from doing that? If the given class is a service, you can simply decorate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible.
You can use an event hook through which you can either execute something before, after or instead of a given action in any controller.

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/event-guide/

Comment: Oh i thought i can only execute some code before and after some action, not instead.I dont have idea how i i missed this article. Thank you